# Accessing Base class variable inside Derived class

Tags: c++11

I have a public inheritance, `Derived` struct inheriting from `Base`. The `Base` has a data member `int i` initialized to 5.

Now I have two codes.

**Code 1** : Compiles fine

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base{

  int i = 5;

};

struct Derived: public Base{

  int j = i; // Derived class able to use variable i from Base

  Derived(){
      i = 10;  // Constructor of Derived able to access i from Base
  }

};

int main()
{
    Derived dobj;

    cout << dobj.i;

    return 0;
}
```

**Code 2** : Gives error

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base{

  int i = 5;

};

struct Derived: public Base{

  int j = i; //Still works

  i = 10; // Error here " main.cpp:15:3: error: ‘i’ does not name a type"

  Derived() = default;

};

int main()
{
    Derived dobj;

    cout<<dobj.i;

    return 0;
}
```

**Why** is it that `i` can be used to assign and be assigned inside constructor body (as in code 1), but not used directly in `Derived` class (as in code 2). Also what does the error mean?

I was under the impression that the scope of `Derived` is nested inside `Base`, so shouldn't it be able to see the data members inside `Base` scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with base and derived classes but with scope. Your code is illegal for the same reason that this code is illegal:

```
struct X
{
    int i;
    i = 20; // error
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/60zPb-

`int i;` or `int i = 10;` are declarations. `i = 20;` is a statement. Statements can only appear in function bodies, not at class (or namespace) scope.

Comment: Makes sense! I did not notice it. Always something new to learn. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, I am right to say that the Derived class "sees" all Base's data members right? (Because of scope nesting)

Comment: @User10482 It's not really about scope. The standard just says they also belong to the derived class: [Unless redeclared in the derived class, members of a base class are also considered to be members of the derived class. Members of a base class other than constructors are said to be inherited by the derived class.](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#derived-2.sentence-8) Whether you can actually see/use them is specified by access control (`public`/`protected`/`private`): http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access